# Is it possible to post a photo to Facebook by a link, not upload?

Tags: php, facebook

Is this possible to create a photo on user/page's timeline not by uploading said photo, but by providing a URL to an already uploaded image? My code so far is this:

```
$response = $fb->api ("/$page_id/photos", 'post', array (
    'name'          => $_description,
    'source'        => $_image_path
));
```

This results in `OAuthException` #324 "Requires upload file". Also, I'd like to photo to be immediately posted on the page's timeline - will it happen, or do I need to make a separate call for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch parameter `source` for `url`, and give it a publicly reachable HTTP URL as value.

But be aware, this only works for photos *not* on Facebook already – feeding it the URL of a photo on Facebook will result in an error message saying that posting photos from their CDN is not possible.